# Programa em C onde tem que remover um aluno de um vetor

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer um programa que faculdade que remover uma aluno de uma vetor, que quando executo o código abaixo, ele exclui o aluno mais deixa um carácter especial no código, podem me ajudar?

```
//Remover o Aluno
void removerAluno(DADOSPES p[], int n)
 {
     char codigo[10];
     int i;
     printf("Digite o Codigo que deseja excluir: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     gets(codigo);
     int encontrou =0;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         if((strcmp(codigo,p[i].codigo))== 0)
         {
            encontrou =1;
         }   
     }
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
        if(encontrou == 1)
          {
            system("cls");
            p[i] = p[i+1];
            p[i].DiaN = p[i+1].DiaN;
            p[n-1].DiaN = 0;
            p[i].MesN = p[i+1].MesN;
            p[n-1].MesN = 0;
            p[i].AnoN = p[i+1].AnoN;
            p[n-1].AnoN = 0;
            p[i].idade = p[i+1].idade;
            p[n-1].idade = 0;
          }
     } 
     printf("Codigo Excluido: %s \n",&codigo );
     system("pause");
     getch();
 }
```

Comment: Bom, o seu código parece estar removendo TODOS os alunos, quando o código digitado é encontrado no meio dos alunos existentes. Você faz dois laços, no primeiro procura pelo código e marca se encontrou. No segundo laço (que é desnecessário, já que poderia ter removido ao encontrar, no primeiro laço) você simplesmente verifica se encontrou e remove EM CADA INTERAÇÃO DO LAÇO. Só isso já não parece muito correto...

Comment: Mas, de todas as formas, o que significa "deixa um caractere especial no código"? Em que código? Como assim?

Comment: Além disso, o `p[i+1]` está acessando um elemento depois do fim do vetor. Em C isso dá merda / resultados imprevisíveis (talvez o caracter esquisito seja devido a isso)

Comment: @hugomg "dá merda" é o melhor termo técnico ever! :)

Answer (score 1):

Como dito por @Luiz Vieira nos comentários da pergunta, os dois laços poderiam ser mesclados. Por exemplos a onde lê-se `encontrou == 1` no segundo laço, poderia ser trocado por `(strcmp(codigo,p[i].codigo))== 0`, evitando de levar a escola a falência e remover todos alunos.

Outro problema é que aparentemente você quer preencher o espaço deixado pelo aluno a ser removido. Como dito pelo companheiro @hugomg nos comentários, ao usar `p[i+1]` você acaba usando um ponteiro para fora da tua tabela quando `i==9`, o que pode causar erros aleatórios em execução.

O que lhe aconselho a fazer é reutilizar o loop, tomando cuidado quando chegar no limite de tua lista. Repare também que eu não removi a parte onde tem `p[i] = p[i+1]`, pois não conheço a estrutura.

```
for(i=0;i<n; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(codigo, p[i].codigo) == 0)
    {
        encontrou = 1;
    }
    if(encontrou == 1 && i < n-1)
    {
        p[i].DiaN = p[i+1].DiaN;
        p[i].MesN = p[i+1].MesN;
        p[i].AnoN = p[i+1].AnoN;
        p[i].idade = p[i+1].idade;
        p[i].codigo = p[i+1].codigo; //???
   }
}
if(encontrou == 1)
{
    p[n-1].MesN = 0;
    p[n-1].DiaN = 0;
    p[n-1].AnoN = 0;
    p[n-1].idade = 0;
}
```

Porem, para responder tua pergunta sobre o caractere especial no fim, pode ser porque você esta passando um pointeiro de `codigo` (que já é em si um ponteiro de char. Como [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf) aceita apenas um ponteiro, voce poderia passar só: `printf("Codigo Excluido: %s \n", codigo);`